# How to install geos on debian raspberry pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, geos, shapely

Hi I am trying to install geos on a raspberry pi running rasbian wheezy so that I can include the shapely modules in my python scripts. 
I tried using: 
`git clone git://git.debian.org/git/pkg-grass/geos`

this downloads properly, but when I try to run my python script it gives me a traceback error saying 
`OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']`

have I put geos in the wrong place? is there a special way to build the files?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just downloaded the sources so far. I guess you wanted to install the binary package instead. To install it, type (as root):

```
apt-get install libgeos++
```

Comment: Strickltly speaking, it is the C API dependency `libgeos-c1` package that is needed

Comment: glad to help you. have fun with your raspy! :)

Comment: @MikeToews Are you sure? I'm not a detailed expert. I just cloned the source code that was linked in the question and had a look into the debian/rules file to see which binary package would be created from the source package. If you have expertize in `shapely` (I don't even know what this is :) and you are sure that only `libgeos-c1` is required, please feel free to edit my post (or undelete yours ;) ....

Comment: @hek2mgl yup, 100% sure: `libgeos-c1` provides `libgeos_c.so` (in the list of files)

Answer (score 3):

Shapely uses the GEOS C API. Install it (and the dependencies) with:

```
apt-get install libgeos-c1
```

Also, if you need the Cython `speedups` for Shapely, you will need:

```
apt-get install libgeos-dev
```