# How check if there is intersection of any two edges given the fixed nodes positions, assuming the edges are drawn as straight lines with networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

**What I want?**

I want to check if there is any interscions beteewn edges in my graph. I have a graph with a lot of vertices and edges.

Here is a simple graph for example:

```
    G = nx.Graph().to_undirected()
    G.add_nodes_from(pos)
    G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=1)
    G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=1)
    G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=1)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

**What I have tried?**

I already tried to use

```
    print(nx.check_planarity(G, False))
```

but because there is an option to draw this graph as a planar graph, the return value is True

**How can I check** if there are edge interscions in my graph?
assuming the position is fixed and the edges are drawn as straight lines

Comment: Since you already have the position, you can compute segments intersection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect

Comment: thanks, but because I have graph with more than 1000 edges I am looking for a method of networkx who does the same.

Comment: Such an implementation would presumably have to be in the [`drawing` submodule](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/layout.py) (as from networkx's point of view this is only relevant for visualization purposes), but there isn't anything that deals with edge crossings.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX does not have this function, you need to implement it yourself ([How can I check if two segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect)) or take it from another library (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417842/how-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-two-line-segments#answer-22487009) from [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)).